# feed urllib a list and ouput results to single file

Tags: python-3.x

I am a total noob but I'm trying to learn some python scripting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have this python script which works, but I'd like to feed it a list of URLs and output the response to a single file. Can some one give me some pointers on how to accomplish this?

SCRIPT:

import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://mysite:1500/blah/blah/blah').read()
print(html)

Comment: Google "python for loop" to get started.

Comment: Thanks, the for loop has me closer...how do I deal with read errors?

line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

import urllib.request

links = ["http://blah/blah1,http://blah/blah2,http://blah/blah3 "]

for j in links:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(j).read()
print(html)

Comment: Well this was not much help...I'll still post the solution once I figure it out.

Comment: Do you mean...import urllib.request

links = [http://blah/blah1,http://blah/blah2,http://blah/blah3]

for j in links:
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(j).read()
 print(html)

I get this syntax error
    print(html)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax